# How do I use themes for R Markdown with github_document as output?

Tags: r

I was told to write a report in R Markdown with the following template:

```
---
title: "Data Dictionary"
output: github_document
date: "Last Updated: `r format(Sys.time(), '%d, %B, %Y at %H:%M')`"
---
```

I want to use readthedown theme from rmdformats package, however I could not find a tutorial on how to do so properly. My question is, is it possible to use a theme with this template? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you already have installed the package, `remotes::install_github("juba/rmdformats")`, just pass `rmdformats::readthedown` to the `output` YAML:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
date: "Last Updated: `r format(Sys.time(), '%d, %B, %Y at %H:%M')`"
output: rmdformats::readthedown
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:

```{r cars}
summary(cars)
```

## Including Plots

You can also embed plots, for example:

```{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
plot(pressure)
```

Note that the `echo = FALSE` parameter was added to the code chunk to prevent printing of the R code that generated the plot.
````

[image: Output]